# Express Router.use requires callback function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, middleware

I am getting following error while trying to add middleware to my application:

```
 throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires callback function');
```

**MyMiddleware.js**

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  var err = checkOptions(options);
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }

  var middleware = function(req, res, next) {
      // do something here
  }

  return middleware;
}
```

This is how I am adding my middleware:

```
var MyMiddleware = require('./server/middlewares/MyMiddleware');
var middleware = MyMiddleware(config);
router.use('/path', middleware);
app.use('/', router);
```

I am using express 4.x version.

Comment: Is this happening when you `throw err`?

Comment: @Jordonias I am getting this error during server start

Comment: @Jordonias No it is not due to throw err

Comment: are you certain? put a `console.log(err);` in the if statement.

Comment: @Jordonias Yes I am 100% certain because I haven't yet implemented checkOptions it is empty method

Comment: I don't see anything here that would be causing this error. You'll have to provide more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60277/discussion-between-jordonias-and-user123).

Answer (score 0):

You define your module as a function, you have to call it.

`var MyMiddleware = require('./server/middlewares/MyMiddleware')();`

Comment: @user123 oh, ok you are actually using it the correct way, ignore my answer, can you `console.log` the `middleware` variable before `router.use`.

Comment: I have a query I am trying to save array using sequelize but I am getting [error: missing dimension value] error.
I am posting the data using http post request as
"tags" : "['JAVA','REST','API']"
I am using postgres as underlying DB